# Getting an error with my custom loss function in Keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I'm creating a custom loss function that incorporates a lot of code and equations. When I try to compile my model as so:

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss=custom_loss(pic), metrics=['accuracy'])

I get an error, which I'm trying to understand how to fix.

Besides that, I also had to change something inside the function for it to run and I'm also interested in changing that back, so I have a total of two problems.

Problem 1:

I get an error, although I made sure to print things during the custom loss function to tell where the error was received and it looks like it was able to run through the entire loss function until the return command. However, the error I got was

```
'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'get_shape'
```

and the more detailed error was:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-254-fe4381ab64e0> in <module>()
----> 1 model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss=custom_loss(pic), metrics= 
['accuracy'])

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in 
compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights, sample_weight_mode, 
weighted_metrics, target_tensors, **kwargs)
    340                 with K.name_scope(self.output_names[i] + 
'_loss'):
    341                     output_loss = weighted_loss(y_true, y_pred,
--> 342                                                 sample_weight, 
mask)
343                 if len(self.outputs) > 1:
344                     self.metrics_tensors.append(output_loss)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in 
weighted(y_true, y_pred, weights, mask)
    415         if weights is not None:
    416             # reduce score_array to same ndim as weight array
--> 417             ndim = K.ndim(score_array)
    418             weight_ndim = K.ndim(weights)
    419             score_array = K.mean(score_array,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-
```

packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in ndim(x)
        617     ```
        618     """
    --> 619     dims = x.get_shape()._dims
        620     if dims is not None:
        621         return len(dims)

The loss function is very long and I am including in this version some printed material because  maybe that can help you understand what the problem is:

```
'''def dl_loss(x,pic):

print('orig shape(x): ',x.shape)
x=tf.reshape(x,[2501,1])
print('try shape(x): ',x.shape)


a=x[0]
print('tfshape(a): ',a.shape)
print('shape(a): ',np.shape(a))
ms=x[1:]
print('tfshape(ms): ',np.shape(ms))




frac=2 
ms_reshaped=tf.reshape(ms,[int(np.shape(pic)[0]/frac),int(np.shape(pic) 
[0]/frac)])
print('got here')
ms=upsample(ms_reshaped,2) #THIS IS MY OWN FUNCTION THAT I ALSO NEED HELP 
WITH
print('finished upsampling')


h=np.shape(pic)[0]
w=np.shape(pic)[1]
print('hot h and w')

cur_noisy=(a*np.ones(np.shape(pic)))*(np.ones(np.shape(pic))+ms)
print('got noisy pic')

cur_clean=pic/(1.000000000001+ms)
print('got clean pic')


avg_m=np.mean(ms)
std_m=np.std(ms)

l_4=0.6*shannon_entropy(np.around(cur_clean,3))
if std_m<0.1:
#   print('in')
    l_4=5*l_4  
print('got l_4')


F_new=im2freq(cur_clean)
F_noisy=im2freq(pic)
print('got fourriers')



l_1=abs(avg_m)
print('got l1')


l_2=-(np.sum(abs(F_noisy[int(np.round(0.5*h)):,int(np.round(0.5*w)):]))
        -np.sum(abs(F_new[int(np.round(0.5*h)):,int(np.round(0.5*w)):])))

l_2=l_2/10000
print('got l2')


m_max=np.max(ms)
m_min=np.min(ms)
std=(m_max-m_min)/3


perc_pix_in_1_std = len(np.where(np.logical_and(ms>(avg_m-std), 
ms<(avg_m+std)))[0])/(np.shape(pic)[0]*np.shape(pic)[1])



l_3=(0.95-perc_pix_in_1_std) #because we're expecting m to be normally 
distributed
print('got l3')
print('final shape: ',np.shape(l_1+l_2+l_4))

return (l_1+l_3+l_4)'''
```

what I get from it is this:
orig shape(x):  (?, 2501)
try shape(x):  (2501, 1)
tfshape(a):  (1,)
shape(a):  (1,)
tfshape(ms):  (2500, 1)
got here
r_size:  50
c_size:  50
finished upsampling
hot h and w
got noisy pic
got clean pic
got l_4
got fourriers
got l1
got l2
got l3
final shape:  ()

which means it did manage to go all the way through the function.

The custom loss that I entered into the compiler was
    '''def custom_loss(pic):

```
def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
return dl_loss(y_pred,pic)

return my_loss'''
```

Problem 2:

```
'''ms=upsample(ms_reshaped,2) #THIS IS MY OWN FUNCTION THAT I ALSO NEED 
HELP WITH
print('finished upsampling')'''
```

the actual upsample definition:
    '''def upsample(pic,frac):
    frac=int(frac)
    r_siz=np.shape(pic)[0]
    print('r_size: ',r_siz)
    c_siz=np.shape(pic)[1]
    print('c_size: ',c_siz)
    new_pic=np.zeros((frac*r_siz,frac*c_siz))
    for i in range(r_siz):
        for j in range(c_siz):

#new_pic[frac*i:frac*i+frac,frac*j:frac*j+frac]=pic[i,j]*np.ones((frac,frac))

```
new_pic[frac*i:frac*i+frac,frac*j:frac*j+frac]=3*np.ones((frac,frac))
return new_pic'''
```

I had to change pic[i,j] to just some random number 3 in order for it to run. I know that the pic that is here is a tensorflow object and when the compiler tries to run, it doesn't have an actual matrix but just a placeholder probably so maybe that's the issue? I though of compiling it and then changing it back. Anyway how can I fix that as well?

Thank you so much for whoever tries to understand the problem!

Comment: Please try to reformat your question, if possible. It is pretty hard to follow. Keras loss functions operate on tensors, not on numpy arrays. If you want to operate on python functions you need to wrap that piece of code with tf.py_function. You can see an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56750620/custom-loss-function-without-using-keras-backend-library/56752804#56752804

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am not understanding why I get the error that I get. The first one, mostly. I guess when that will be solved, I'll ask about the second problem I have.

Comment: The error that you are getting is because you are returning NumPy arrays from a loss function, which you can't. The loss function job is to create nodes in the computational graph. It doesn't execute the operations. Thus the recommendation to use tf.py_function.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response @Pedo Marques , I'm trying to change all of my code to tensorflow but I am getting stuck. I want to tranfrom:

'pic[1:3,1:3] = other_pic[5,6]*np.ones((2,2))'
 #didn't check that the indexes match, just giving an example

so I am trying to do the variable assignment and won't let me assign for more than just one place in the matrix, so I'm trying to assign a few times and after the first time of assignment it gives me an error.

Comment: my code:
    'aa = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2,3]))
    a=1
    init_op=tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
      sess.run(init_op)
      print(aa.eval())
      aa=tf.assign(aa[a*0,a*0+1],1,use_locking=False)
      print(aa.eval())
  

      aa=tf.assign(aa[a*0+1,a*0+1],1,use_locking=False)
      print(aa.eval())'

@PedroMarques

Comment: Keren, can you please try to reformat your question using backticks to format code blocks. 3 backticks (`) start/end a code block. And please try to include enough details so that someone can try to reproduce your setup.

Comment: Okay. I worked on my code all day yesterday and now I have the following question: 
    ```def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.py_function(func=loss,inp=[y_pred,pic], Tout=tf.float32)
    def custom_loss(pic):
    return my_loss```

I want to call my loss function that receives as inputs a picture and the y_prediction. 
1. Is it correct to assume that the y_pred will be a tensorflow object?
2. In my loss function (not my_loss or custom_loss but loss - the one I call to with tf.py_function), can I treat y_pred as a numpy array and perform numpy operations on it?

Comment: If I want to use the following:
```model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss=custom_loss(pic), metrics=['accuracy'])```

@PedroMarques

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56789954/11057642

I reasked my question here, it it also written more clearly.