# How to create a custom keras loss function with opencv?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, keras, computer-vision

I'm developing a machine learning model using keras and I notice that the available losses functions are not giving the best results on my test set.

I am using an Unet architecture, where I input a (16,16,3) image and the net also outputs a (16,16,3) picture (auto-encoder). I notice that maybe one way to improve the model would be if I used a loss function that compares pixel to pixel on the gradients (laplacian) between the net output and the ground truth. However, I did not found any tutorial that would handle this kind of application, because it would need to use opencv laplacian function on each output image from the net.

The loss function would be something like this:

```py
def laplacian_loss(y_true, y_pred):

  # y_true already is the calculated gradients, only needs to compute on the y_pred
  # calculates the gradients for each predicted image
  y_pred_lap = []
  for img in y_pred:
    laplacian = cv2.Laplacian( np.float64(img), cv2.CV_64F )
    y_pred_lap.append( laplacian )

  y_pred_lap = np.array(y_pred_lap)

  # mean squared error, according to keras losses documentation
  return K.mean(K.square(y_pred_lap - y_true), axis=-1)
```

Has anyone done something like that for loss calculation?

Comment: Please take a moment to format your code example using 3 backticks (`) for start and end of a code block.

Comment: Check if the following helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56750620/custom-loss-function-without-using-keras-backend-library/56752804#56752804

Comment: I think this helps, but I don't really know the shape and type of y_true and y_pred. My model trains with batch size equals to 256. Does it changes something?

Comment: ```K.shape(tensor)``` returns a tensor with the shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to reach a easy solution. The main feature was that the gradient calculation is actually a 2D filter. For more information about it, please follow the [link](https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/OpenCV_Python/python_opencv3_Image_Gradient_Sobel_Laplacian_Derivatives_Edge_Detection.php) about the laplacian kernel. In that matter, is necessary that the output of my network be filtered by the laplacian kernel. For that, I created an extra convolutional layer with fixed weights, exactly as the laplacian kernel. After that, the network will have two outputs (one been the desired image, and the other been the gradient's image). So, is also necessary to define both losses.

To make it clearer, I'll exemplify. In the end of the network you'll have something like:

```
channels = 3 # number of channels of network output
lap = Conv2D(channels , (3,3), padding='same', name='laplacian') (net_output)
model = Model(inputs=[net_input], outputs=[net_out, lap])
```

Define how you want to calculate the losses for each output:

```
# losses for output, laplacian and gaussian
losses = {
"enhanced": "mse",
"laplacian": "mse"
}
lossWeights = {"enhanced": 1.0, "laplacian": 0.6}
```

Compile the model:

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss=losses, loss_weights=lossWeights)
```

Define the laplacian kernel, apply its values in the weights of the above convolutional layer and set trainable equals False (so it won't be updated).

```
bias = np.asarray([0]*3)
# laplacian kernel
l = np.asarray([
  [[[1,1,1],
  [1,-8,1],
  [1,1,1]
  ]]*channels
  ]*channels).astype(np.float32)
bias = np.asarray([0]*3).astype(np.float32)
wl = [l,bias]
model.get_layer('laplacian').set_weights(wl)
model.get_layer('laplacian').trainable = False
```

When training, remember that you need two values for the ground truth:

```
model.fit(x=X, y = {"out": y_out, "laplacian": y_lap})
```

**Observation:** Do not utilize the BatchNormalization layer! In case you use it, the weights in the laplacian layer will be updated!

Answer (score 2):

Given the code above, it seems that it would be equivalent to using a Lambda() layer as the output layer that applies that transformation in the image, before considering the mean square error.

Regardless as whether it is implemented as a Lambda() layer or in the loss function; the transformation needs to be such that Tensorflow understands how to calculate the gradients. The simplest was to do this would probably be to reimplement the cv2.Laplacian computation using Tensorflow math operations.

In order to use the cv2 library directly, you need to create a function that calculates the gradients for what happens inside the cv2 lib; that seems significantly more error prone.

Gradient descent optimisation relies on being able to compute gradients from the inputs to the loss; and back. Any operation in the middle must be differentiable; and Tensorflow must understand the math operations for auto differentiation to work; or you need to add them manually.